# How can I add a color filter to a HTML page?

Tags: html, css, canvas, colors

I would like to have a box (div or canvas?) that filters all the colors that are behind that box.
Like for example I would like to remove all colors except red, or turn everything B&W except yellow.

I tried using a canvas or CSS filters but without luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525530/colormatrix-css-filter-to-convert-blackwhite-image-to-duotone but it does not seem to work anymore (devtools says the -webkit-filter property is invalid)

Comment: Just remove the "-webkit-" before "filter". And check out about css vendor prefixes.