# Load and transform and embed an SVG file with svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I'm using the [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/) library to load an svg file, to add its points (images) and to animate the points. I load the svg file in PHP and generate the code to embed it in the html.

Here is how my html code looks:

```
<div class="svg-element">
    <svg id="svgId" ...>
        <!-- SVG code -->
    </svg>
</div>
```

This is how my javascript code looks:

```
var svg = SVG.get('svgId');
svg.size('100%', '100%');

var point = svg.image(point_url);
point.attr('id', 'pointId');
point.move(100, 100);
```

That code works perfectly but the problem comes when I use the [`scale()`](http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#scale) function to make a zoom effect with the points.

```
point.scale(0.5);
```

or the [`transform`](http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#transform) function:

```
point.transform({scaleX : '0.5', scaleY : '0.5'});
```

A `TypeError: SVG.parser is undefined` error is shown in the javascript console.

How can I avoid that problem and use the transform method with the images? The problem may be that I use the `.get()` function, how I can create the `SVG` object with the svg file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is silly and easy:

```
var svg = SVG('svgId');
```

instead of using the [`.get()`](http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#referencing-elements) function.

You have to use the `SVG()` constructor with the SVG id, not the `.get()` function, I'm confused with this because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17303911/793246) says that you can use `.get()` to retrieve the SVG.

Comment: The linked answer also says: " method *after* importing raw svg:". The get method is for elements in the svg doc not the doc itself