# Load SVG file with svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I've seen several Questions related to this topic in SO and followed them ([Loading a SVG file with svg.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911246/loading-a-svg-file-with-svg-js)) and no success trying to load a svg file.

```
__this.canvas = SVG('canvas').size(500, 500);
$.get('/cuentos/Rapunzel/prueba.svg', function(data) {
     __this.data = data;
     console.log(__this.data);
     __this.canvas.svg(__this.data);
});
```

__this.canvas is type of **svgjs.Doc** which is imported in the following manner:

```
import SVG from './node_modules/svg.js/svg.js';
declare var svgjs: (domElement: HTMLElement) => svgjs.Library;
```

The error:

[image]

There's something i'm doing wrong or missing.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery's `$.get`, for SVGs, gives back a DOM object representing the SVG by default. SVG.js's `svg` function, however, expects a string.

You can simply force JQuery to give back a string like that:

```
$.get('/cuentos/Rapunzel/prueba.svg', function(data) {
   __this.data = data;
   console.log(__this.data);
   __this.canvas.svg(__this.data);
}, 'text');
```

PS: I opened up a PR against SVG.js to display a proper error message for that case: https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/pull/870

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery this form works in both 2.7.1 and 3.0.x i tested

```
    var svgp = SVG($('#<name of svg>')[0]);
```