# Modifying external SVG using CSS, inside a container

Tags: html, css, svg

I have something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <embed src="files/image.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="my-svg" />
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Sub title</h2>
</div>
```

Coupled with a stylesheet, `style.css`, that is referenced in my HTML file, along with the external SVG file like so:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
```

What I'm looking to do is change the fill of the SVG when the container is rolled over. Is this possible with pure CSS?

I know it's possible to do something like this in the css;

```
rect:hover {
    fill: white;
}
```

But, is it possible to do something along the lines of this?

```
.container:hover rect {
    fill: white;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue with an answer from [Drew Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503546/drew-baker)

[How to change color of SVG image using CSS (jQuery SVG image replacement)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11978995/1276142)

Turns out you have to make the DOM of the SVG "visible".

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery. simply

```
 $('.container').mouseover(function(){

    $('rect').css('fill', 'white');


});
```

Comment: Turns out this only seems to work when the SVG is in-line, not external, unless I'm missing something?