# How to change the color of an svg?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

I'd like to draw an svg file on a canvas.The current code is like below:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = "simple SVG.svg";
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

But how to change the color of the svg showed on canvas, WITHOUT using *canvg*
and *embedded script*(means modify the origin svg file is forbidden)?
Is reading the svg file and replacing "fill=" a possible way?

Comment: <img id="yourcanvas" class="svg link" src="/images/simpleSVG.svg"/>


You will find your joy here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement

Comment: close, but I'm drawing the svg on a canvas, make it more complicated.