# fill property not working for SVGs

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, svg

I get my SVGs from thenounproject.com, however i cannot change their color as fill does nothing.

I am using Ruby on Rails, so I used <%= image_tag('#'), :class => "tomatoe" %>

and my css looks like this

```
.tomatoe{
    @include transition-property(all);  
    @include transition-duration(1s);
    fill: white;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Fill never works, tried it on several SVGs but no luck and I have no clue why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't customize a SVG with CSS by importing it through an img tag, you'll have to embed the SVG code in your HTML in order to achieve this.

The accepted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement) question has an interesting approach, by replacing every img tag by inline SVG to allow CSS styling.

Comment: Never thought it would be this complicated. Was kind of hoping for a pure CSS way of doing this but this will have to do. Thanks!

Comment: It is a pure CSS approach. It is just that CSS does not apply across object boundaries.  The external SVG file is a different object to the HTML file.  You resolve that by embedding the SVG as Alcides says.