# Recolor an SVG image via CSS "fill" doesn't work

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to recolor a simple SVG image with CSS (as I saw here http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/evcBu ):

My HTML:
`<img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12091580/rwdicon/icon-menu.svg" class="myMenu" alt="menu">`

My CSS:
`.myMenu { fill: red; }`

It's not working (see http://jsfiddle.net/sexyzane/1hojaccb/ )!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fill` is used for svg *[**element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) markup*, you have an `img` element with an `svg` source, as such you cannot use `fill` to change the image color.

Instead, if you want to colorize the image, you may want to look into applying a [**CSS filter**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) effect to the `img` tag, although this may not be able to achieve the exact result you're after.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/6hq739p5/)