# Add onclick to svg path by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement) Stackoverflow question and the first answer, I was able to convert an SVG image to inline svg on document ready. I can also reference its path' elements from CSS to add a hover stroke.

The next thing I am trying to accomplish is add onclick to each path without having to add it to the svg file itself. I assumed since the CSS can identify each path's class, I should also be able to identify each path's ID in javascript as well, but I am having trouble figuring out how. Here's my code:

```
 <body>
        <div id="mapSideBar" class="left">
        </div>
        <div id="mapMain" class="left">
            <img id = "mapImg" src="canada2.svg" class="logo" />

        </div>

    </body>
```

I have the function mentioned in the link above to convert it to inline SVG and my paths have ids - path1, path2, path3 and path4. I tried to add the following to the `jQuery(document).ready()` function:

```
var $paths = jQuery(document).find('path');
$paths.each(function() {
    (this).click(onImgClick((this).id));
});
```

just to see if I could get a handle on each path, and I cannot. Is there something I am missing, or is there even a way to assign onclick event handlers to each path?

Thank you,
Rishi

Comment: Can you show a little more of the HTML?

Comment: Any reason you're not just putting the svg tag into the html document?  (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp)

Comment: @SlipperyPete, the relevant HTML is shown because the jQuery function takes care of converting the SVG image to inline. Essentially, there is one div on the page which I have shown in the edited post.

Comment: @thebjorn, I do not own/create the image. It is retrieved from a data source and I only dictate the IDs of the paths. I would have to change code to account for a slightly modified, albeit identically functioning, image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a working solution : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uaw348so/)

**HTML** :

```
<img class="svg" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e5/My_Little_Pony_Friendship_is_Magic_logo.svg"/>
```

**CSS** :

```
svg path:hover {
    fill: red !important;
}
```

**JavaScript** :

```
/*
 * Replace all SVG images with inline SVG
 */
jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
    var $img = jQuery(this);
    var imgID = $img.attr('id');
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
        // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
        var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

        // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
        }
        // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
        }

        // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

        // Replace image with new SVG
        $img.replaceWith($svg);

        // Add an handler
        jQuery('path').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).click(function() {alert(jQuery(this).attr('id'));});                       
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Now on to learning the difference between $(..) and jQuery(..)

Comment: There is no difference at all, $(..) is an alias to jQuery(..).

Comment: Weird. $('path') didn't return an array of paths, but jQuery('path') in your solution does. That made me question the difference between the two.

Comment: Either you have another JavaScript framework using $(..) or you called $('path') after jQuery.get(...) and not in the callback function and so because jQuery.get(...) is asynchronous it was called before any "path" was actually there.

Comment: Here is the same [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jbumc07/15/) using $(..) instead of jQuery(..).

Comment: great answer! perfect

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(document).ready()` is not enough to ensure that your inline svg has been correctly loaded.

To validate if this is the actual issue, add a timeout to your function and see if it works better.

Eventually, what you'll probably need to do is add a callback to the function that does the inline svg conversion.