# Inline SVG with separate SVG file

Tags: html, css, svg

my ultimate goal is displaying images on my webpage which I can easily adjust the color of.

Currently I am doing it with inline SVG; like so:

```
        <a href="https://thechymera.tumblr.com">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="32" height="32" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <path class="social" d="M 100,0 0,0 0,100 100,100 z M 71.028,79.925 c -2.886,1.358 -5.506,2.315 -7.848,2.865 -2.344,0.545 -4.877,0.819 -7.599,0.819 -3.092,0 -4.917,-0.388 -7.291,-1.166 -2.375,-0.784 -4.402,-1.902 -6.077,-3.337 -1.681,-1.447 -2.841,-2.986 -3.49,-4.612 -0.65,-1.628 -0.972,-3.99 -0.972,-7.082 l 0,-23.714 -9.187,0 0,-9.576 c 2.655,-0.861 5.736,-2.099 7.626,-3.708 1.899,-1.615 3.418,-3.547 4.564,-5.807 1.149,-2.255 1.938,-5.132 2.369,-8.62 l 9.618,0 0,15.642 15.635,0 0,12.071 -15.637,0 0,17.34 c 0,3.924 -0.051,6.185 0.366,7.297 0.413,1.106 1.447,2.255 2.574,2.919 1.498,0.898 3.207,1.346 5.132,1.346 3.425,0 6.832,-1.112 10.216,-3.338 l 0,10.665 0,-0.004 z"></path>
        </a>
```

(And specifying my colors in a linked `.css` file:

```
svg:hover .social { fill: #efa5d6; }
svg .social { fill: #b5b5b5; }
```

).

I get the `d="<...>"` values by `cat`ing my SVG files.

**My complaint with this method is:**

I do not load the image from an editable source. I cannot directly edit the HTML if I want to change details in my image. I either have to copy the path values into a new SVG file, or keep the exact corresponding SVG file on record. after I am done editing, I can't just `rsync` and rely on the fact that my HTML is still pointing to the same file, rather I have to edit the HTML as well and paste the path value. This easily adds 2-1000 further steps to my workflow, which, for a trial-and-error designer such as myself is quite significant.

Is there anyway to keep the capabilities (shown above) and wide support offered by inline SVG without *actually* inlining the SVG, but rather loading it from a different location?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement

Comment: I had in fact seen that thread before I decided for inline SVG. The reason I still decided on that was that the jquery code didn't work for me, and I don't know how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Ah, yeah, his php answer maybe work, I suppose it depends on your external source specs, I'm curious to seeing how weird you could get using ajax to try this.  I was curious about this as well, for a d3 project, but I moved away from it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The way I've done it before is by using a server-side script to include the SVG file into an element on the page, like this:

```
<div id="my-svg-image">
    <?php include "image.svg"; ?>
</div>
```

By wrapping it, I can target the specific SVG with CSS without having to know whether the file contains an ID or not, or to specifically target instances of the image. Although I haven't tried yet, it stands to reason that some sort of AJAX-like request could be made to grab the SVG instead.

Comment: I want to use this on a static website (no server-side magick whatsoever)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/yupago/edit

```
svgUrl = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/University_of_Tirana_logo.svg';


$("#svg").load(svgUrl + " svg", function() {  

$("#svg").find('path').css({fill:'#000'});
    //do stuff
});
```