# Hot to get svg inside a span using jQuery's find()

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I'm having difficulties selecting a svg element (actually written like img and converted later to svg using jQuery).

The code is:

Html:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="personas" class="active">
    <span id="boton_auto"><img class="svg" src="img/auto.svg" /></span>
</div></div>
```

and jQuery

```
$(".tab-content div span").find( "svg" ).addClass("activo");
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: out of curiosity, how are you converting it to svg ?

Comment: I link you to the commentary where I got that code http://stackoverflow.com/a/11978996/1880249

Comment: do you want to add any events to that converted svg ?

Comment: it should turn to white using css (which works).

Comment: the image conversion happens slowly so if you have `$(".tab-content div span").find( ".svg" )` right after conversion it won't work

Comment: how should I proceed? Thanks

Comment: something like this http://jsbin.com/yemuta/2/edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the dot before svg

or the whole line could be:
`$(".tab-content .svg").addClass("activo");`

**edit:**
I looked at the code that replaces it with an svg. It get's it asynchronously. Are you running your find line before its done?
Try adding the line directly after the line `$img.replaceWith($svg);`

Comment: it's the same, the selector dont get the svg element