# How to manage SVG inline in HTML well

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there any way to manage SVG inline well?

I'm trying to use `img` tag with `SVG`, but `CSS` can't control the hover style.

I wish to make `HTML` more simple, not so many inline `SVG.`

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/o0bfuqa3/1/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement

Answer (score 2):

The SVG has to be inline in the DOM to be styleable via CSS.

You can achive this by using an SVG injector, that replaces the `<img>` tag with the SVG.
For example with [SVGInject](https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject) you can simply add the SVG like this:

`<img src="image.svg" onload="SVGInject(this)" />`

The attribute `onload="SVGInject(this)"` makes sure that the injection is done after the SVG has loaded.

*Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of the mentioned SVG injector.*

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your svg file into a font so that you can apply more hover styles that you want. I wish this helps. Try going to this site [icomoon.io](http://icomoon.io/)