# SVG + CSS - how to include in HTML and scale & color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I ma trying to understand how to include a SVG as a class and manipulate it via CSS for hover etc.

I got the following svg example from icomoon. The purpose is to avoid a number of http requests in a page and include as much icon information into a CSS using class.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><g id="icomoon-ignore">
</g>
<path d="M192 232c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path>
<path d="M352 232c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path>
<path d="M192 392c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path>
<path d="M352 392c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path>
<path d="M456.041 80l55.959-55.958v-24.042h-24.041l-55.959 55.958-55.959-55.958h-24.041v24.042l55.959 55.958-55.959 55.958v24.042h24.041l55.959-55.958 55.959 55.958h24.041v-24.042z"></path>
<path d="M0 384h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
<path d="M0 288h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
<path d="M416 224h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
<path d="M416 416h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
<path d="M416 320h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
<path d="M0 192h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
<path d="M0 96h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
<path d="M256 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
<path d="M160 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
<path d="M64 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
<path d="M224 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
<path d="M320 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
<path d="M128 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
<path d="M32 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
</svg>
```

I know from codepen example that if I just include it as a html code - it will work.  (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epvLgO)

But what I want to do is something like

```
.icon {
     <insert the contents of the svg file here>
}

.icon:hover {
fill: red ;
}
```

and then in html do something like

```
<span class="icon"></span>
```

also - for this icon - how can I change the size on the fly for various medias ?

meaning

if iphone, I want to set the icon size differently...

```
.icon {
width: 32px;
heigh: 32px;
}
```

thanks..  (this is to see how I can reduce the total number of http call - by using SVG and CSS)

Comment: This might help you, although it doesn't cut down on HTTP requests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement/11978996

Comment: I think you've painted yourself into a corner here. You could make the SVG a background image and embed it into the CSS as a data URI but if you did that you can't change the fill on hover. If you just wanted to make it less opaque on hover that would be doable.

Comment: I suppose you could use a different red image on hover though. You'd have the image data twice though which would double the bandwidth required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your SVG code in CSS like this:

```
.icon {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M192 232c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M352 232c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M192 392c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M352 392c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M456.041 80l55.959-55.958v-24.042h-24.041l-55.959 55.958-55.959-55.958h-24.041v24.042l55.959 55.958-55.959 55.958v24.042h24.041l55.959-55.958 55.959 55.958h24.041v-24.042z"></path><path d="M0 384h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M0 288h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M416 224h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M416 416h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M416 320h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M0 192h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M0 96h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M256 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M160 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M64 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M224 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M320 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M128 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M32 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path></svg>')
}
```

but then you cannot change its style becuase the svg isn’t DOM object.

You can just put SVG codes inside span tag like this:

HTML

```
<span class="icon">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <path d="M192 232c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path>
    <path d="M352 232c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path>
    <path d="M192 392c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path>
    <path d="M352 392c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path>
    <path d="M456.041 80l55.959-55.958v-24.042h-24.041l-55.959 55.958-55.959-55.958h-24.041v24.042l55.959 55.958-55.959 55.958v24.042h24.041l55.959-55.958 55.959 55.958h24.041v-24.042z"></path>
    <path d="M0 384h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
    <path d="M0 288h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M416 224h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
    <path d="M416 416h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
    <path d="M416 320h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
    <path d="M0 192h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
    <path d="M0 96h32v64h-32v-64z"></path>
    <path d="M256 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
    <path d="M160 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
    <path d="M64 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
    <path d="M224 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
    <path d="M320 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
    <path d="M128 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
    <path d="M32 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path>
  </svg>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.icon {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.icon:hover svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

if you really want to put SVG codes only in CSS:

```
.icon {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M192 232c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M352 232c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M192 392c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M352 392c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M456.041 80l55.959-55.958v-24.042h-24.041l-55.959 55.958-55.959-55.958h-24.041v24.042l55.959 55.958-55.959 55.958v24.042h24.041l55.959-55.958 55.959 55.958h24.041v-24.042z"></path><path d="M0 384h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M0 288h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M416 224h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M416 416h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M416 320h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M0 192h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M0 96h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M256 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M160 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M64 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M224 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M320 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M128 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M32 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path></svg>')
}
.icon:hover {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="red"><path d="M192 232c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M352 232c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M192 392c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M352 392c0 13.2-10.8 24-24 24h-48c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24v-48c0-13.2 10.8-24 24-24h48c13.2 0 24 10.8 24 24v48z"></path><path d="M456.041 80l55.959-55.958v-24.042h-24.041l-55.959 55.958-55.959-55.958h-24.041v24.042l55.959 55.958-55.959 55.958v24.042h24.041l55.959-55.958 55.959 55.958h24.041v-24.042z"></path><path d="M0 384h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M0 288h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M416 224h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M416 416h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M416 320h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M0 192h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M0 96h32v64h-32v-64z"></path><path d="M256 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M160 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M64 64h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M224 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M320 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M128 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path><path d="M32 480h64v32h-64v-32z"></path></svg>')
}
```

You can assign different style by screen sizes with media query. For example, if you want to target devices with screen width smaller than 480px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .icon {
    width: 32px;
    heigh: 32px;
  }
}
```

Of course you cannot distinguish between iPhone and Android with this method. If you have to, you should use [javascripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery#3540295). You can also check just if the device is [touch enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript#4819886) or not.

Comment: thanks- I think this is the closest I can create. doubling the bw - but reducing overall https request.