# Image/SVG change color?

Tags: html, css, svg

---

So I've been developing something, and I have decided to use SVGs. However, there are multiple themes for my application, is there anyway I can change the color of the SVG, like a white, to a black, through css? I'm not looking at filtering, as I can't apply so the entire image is like solid red. For an example, I have an image, svg or not, with a white icon. But I want a red icon instead. Is there anyway to do this? I prefer to not use inline svg, as it will complicate customization.
If you require any clarification, please notify me. Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
Some extra code:

```
<img class="fullscreen" src="assets/icons/ic_fullscreen.svg" />
```

**EDIT:** JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MashedPotatoes/s2gs3t16/1/

Comment: Please, post you jsfiddle

Comment: I have added a fiddle now

Comment: Please, add the svg to the jsfiddle

Comment: I will make it so, but I will have to use inline svg, as I have a hard time uploading images to imgur :). I'm quite sure you get the idea however, I can explain.

Comment: I want to clarify a bit. I'm using an svg file in my project that is accessed through an `<image>` tag. I want to be able to change the fill color of the svg.

Comment: You can change the color, I hop these links can help you. (https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/) and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92625/discussion-between-alireza-safian-and-mashedpotatoes).

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into the same problem a few months ago. I eventually wrote something that provided me what we're both looking for - use the same SVG and have CSS to change its color. The idea is that you create it via `<object>` and then do some DOM manipulation on its content to replace it with a `<div>` and thus providing access to the content.

I wrote a little post about the process [here](http://omriaharon.blogspot.co.il/) - you could see the solution and take what you need. Also - the code is a directive in AngularJS so it might not suit you, but the idea is the same, you could take it and use it in Javascript/Jquery.

**If you're using Angular:**

You can use this component - [ngReusableSvg](https://github.com/OmriAharon/ngReusableSvg).

Comment: Thanks! I will look into your article.

Comment: Cool, I would be glad to use this. But I'm not using angular, and I'm also dynamically changing the source of the image... Can you help a bit?

Answer (score 0):

You can't dinamically change colors of a background SVG. But in most cases you can do it changing the container's background color using the SVG as a "mask".

`clip-path: url(#clipping)` http://codepen.io/yoksel/full/fsdbu/