# convert function with multiple .get() inside jQuery .each to q promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, q

I'm using the excellent answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11978996/3092596) to convert svg images into inline html.

The function looks through the container or body, finds each `.svg` image 
and converts them to inline html.

However, it uses a `$.get()` call to retrieve the svg files
which makes the function asynchronous.

I'd like to convert the function to a promise so that I can wait for it to complete before running other things (like adding or removing classes to the new inline html etc)

My current attempt looks like this:

```
util.convertSvgImages = function(container) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    container = typeof container !== 'undefined' ? container : $("body");

    var getsToComplete = jQuery('img.svg', container).length;   // the total number of $get.() calls to complete within the $.each() loop
    var getsCompleted = 0;                                      // the current number of $get.() calls completed (counted within the $get.() callback)

    jQuery('img.svg', container).each(function(index) {
        var img = jQuery(this);
        var imgID = img.attr('id');
        var imgClass = img.attr('class');
        var imgURL = img.attr('src');
        jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
            getsCompleted += 1;

            var svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');                         // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest

            if (typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {                         // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
                svg = svg.attr('id', imgID);
            }

            if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                svg = svg.attr('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg');    // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            }

            svg = svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');                            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org

            svg.attr('class', img.attr("data-svg_class") + " svg");     // add class to svg object based on the image data-svg_class value

            $('rect', svg).attr("stroke", "").attr("fill", "");
            $('line', svg).attr("stroke", "").attr("fill", "");
            $('path', svg).attr("stroke", "").attr("fill", "");
            $('polyline', svg).attr("stroke", "").attr("fill", "");
            $('polygon', svg).attr("stroke", "").attr("fill", "");
            $('circle', svg).attr("stroke", "").attr("fill", "");

            img.replaceWith(svg);                                       // Replace image with new SVG

            if (getsCompleted === getsToComplete){
                deferred.resolve('OK');
            }
        }, 'xml');
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

What is the best way to use promises within asynchronous calls inside an `$.each()` loop ?  Using `q.all()` ?

Comment: Yes, you should use `Q.all`. [Do not use `Q.defer()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572), just go for `Q($.get(imgUrl)).then(…)`

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.get` returns a promise, so, you can use that, and jquery.map to make an array of promises that can be used in `q.all` (or `Promise.all` for that matter )

```
util.convertSvgImages = function(container) {
    // ... snip
    var promises = jQuery('img.svg', container).map(function(index) {
        // ... snip
        return jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
            // ... snip
        }, 'xml');
    });
    return q.all(promises);
};
```

usage

`util.convertSvgImages().then(.....)`

Note: if any .get fails, the Q.all will `reject` **as soon as there is a failure** rather than `resolve` once all .gets have finished ... you may want to use `q.allSettled` instead - this will wait for all `.get` to finish (success or fail) and you can check for failures in your `.then` code. see documentation for [q.allSettled](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)