# On mouse hover/unhover parent element, change url hash of children image

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an `<li>` with an `<img>` inside.
I want pick each one by his class or id.
This `<img>` is an SVG with *#black* and *#white* versions, and his url in my HTML ends with *#black* as default.
What I need:
When I hover `<li>` I need that the 's url end changes from *#black* to *#white*, and when user unhover, changes again to *#black*.
How can I manipulate end of texts (**#** at `<img url="">` in this example) in Javascript?

Thanks in advance, and I believe that answers in this topic will help other users as well.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to switch the url, but also switch the svg to show the hover, or do you mean you want to change the src of the img tag?

Comment: Please put your sample code. Then, we can write the exact functional code

Comment: @Kaiido Do you know about SVG? Insertind a hash at end of img url can change the SVG group displayed, as an completly different image.
I want exactly what I'm explaining in text. The "unreason" for you of insert a hash after image url dont make my answer "unclear".

Comment: The # can be changed, just show us the complete html markup eg. <img src="something#black">

Comment: if you're just looking to switch an image on hover you can get that done with css, we are just unsure of what your code is trying to do.

Comment: @yezzz I have various li with one image in each. I want change the hash of all to change its color in hover effects. The complete html markup is <img src="something#black">. I need a script that uses the class/id of <li> for trigger hover/unhover effects to change hash of <img> url toggling #black/#white.

Comment: @Matt Trueblood I've searched and we can't change SVG color trought <img> with CSS.

Comment: @DaniellMesquita, sorry forgot mention there is a javascript part, look here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement>

Comment: @MattTrueblood oh, then I can do it with CSS throught jQuery. This will be usefull for the part I want. But my project have other dynamic parts that I need maintain user's favorite image URL and automatically change a #hash of image url. How can I change the hash of an image url?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this trick aren't what I want. I don't want a <svg> renderized in my project instead of image. Then, using the #hash is the best solution for me. Thanks for compreenssion.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2:

(you can replace "img" with your selector if you like)

```
$("li.navi-item").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("img").attr("src", $(this).find("img").attr("src").replace("#black", "#white"));
}, function() {
  $(this).find("img").attr("src", $(this).find("img").attr("src").replace("#white", "#black"));
});
```

**put the code inside your $(document).ready(function () { }**

Comment: Thanks, this is very near, but.... ....sorry, this is code is not very good. The <img> is children of a <div> that is children of the referred <li>. This code can be more acurrate hiring the id/class instead of parental order.

Comment: $("li.myclass").hover(function(){
     $("img.myclass").attr("src").replace("#black", "#white");
     }, function(){
     $("img.myclass").attr("src").replace("#white", "#black");
}); can work better, with direct infalible referencing.

Comment: .navi-item is the class of <li>, and .navi-img is the class of <img>.

Comment: sorry, I realise code is flawed... will update in 5 seconds

Comment: can probably make better logic, just need to know if it's desired behavior

Comment: the image isn't changing, and this code don't refers to a img class.

Comment: this site is not a code writing service. I expected you to adapt the classes to your needs. I've now added class to li, did not change img, as it will find the img IF IT IS a child of the LI.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for trying, but this code don't work. I've tryed adapt this code to call img's class, but have failed. This is the commit of my current workflow https://github.com/Software-js/WS.js/commit/8dd0a59bcdf55579e704a16f5234f6ffac60bb28

Comment: first have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/xmdpqso9/ and check the img src on hover/unhover. Is that the desired behavior?

Comment: sorry, this is working very well, but the problem I'm facing is that this not refers direct to <img> class. This needs refer <img> class instead of parental order.

Comment: can you update that fiddle to match your html structure etc?

Comment: This code can be direct and generic to help not only me, but other users that can need this on future. Is impossible refer to <img> ID instead of use HTML families? I've tryed and not worked. Please help me with <img> ID.

Comment: yes I can target an img class or single element ID, but I need to know what your html looks like... your github commit is too much info... a single demo page maybe?

Comment: is located in "Dashboard" menu, where the hover effect is needed in <img> icons.

Comment: yeah I see it, when hover li it should only change the grandchild img... correct? And I do see why current code not working

Comment: Replaced .children with .find as it needs to travel more than 1 level down... https://jsfiddle.net/xmdpqso9/1/

Comment: I've inserted, and surprisely don't worked! =/ software-js.github.io/WS.js/live

Comment: Genial! Thank you very much! It worked! Now I can continue working in this project. Thanks so much ;)