# SVG as background image - changing color

Tags: css, svg

This is my code:

```
div.gray-box-1 {
background: #f1f1f1 url('gfx/p1.svg') no-repeat center center;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

p1.svg is an image of cat. I want to change the color of it on hover. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean the `fill` color? If so, you cannot do that **unless** the SVG is inline (not file url) or embedded in the HTML.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement