# I need to inline svg from urls

Tags: javascript, svg, angular

I need to inline SVG files from urls.
I'm not sure if it is important, but we are using Angular 2

I need to convert this

```
<img src='svg/workspace.svg'>
```

into this at runtime

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 18 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fit="">
  <path d="M13.95 4.05A7 7 0 1 0 15.93 10H13.9A5 5 0 0 1 4 9a5 5 0 0 1 8.536-3.536L10 8h6V2l-2.05 2.05z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
</svg>
```

Is there a library to do this?

---

**Update**

At this point we tried [inlineHTML] from angular, but it "sanitizes" the svg, and we end up with nothing

---

**Update 2** a solution

We gave up and ended using the `<use>` tag inside the `<svg>` tag

```
<svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
      attr.xlink:href="svg/{{workspace.svgName}}.svg#icon"
></use></svg>
```

attr is required because angular2 didn't understand plan xlint:href, the result is similar to inlined SVG, but we have to edit the SVG files to remove width, height and fill tags.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense to do this at runtime. Is there more background information that we need to understand why you're doing this? (I ask because this is a possible [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement

Comment: we have a lot of templates with <img src='...svg'> and some of them are using data binding, that why we need it be automatic