# Link External SVG into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I am making SVG animations, and would like to use some Javascript. I know about the SVG element, but I am modifying my SVG through Inkscape, so I would like to just link it in. I really would like to be able to use CSS to manipulate the SVG.

How do I link it in so that I can modify it, but not need to have the entire SVG document copied into the HTML file.

Comment: You can just use `img`'s `src` property.

Comment: Yes, Jack, but I think they want to actually use CSS on the SVG elements... Check out this great blog on the subject: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Something like this perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement