# Modify SVG with CSS as background-image

Tags: jquery, css, svg, sass

I was wondering if there's a way to access SVG via CSS when using them like:

```
.logo {
...
  background-image: url("../VectorImages/logo.svg");
}
```

I found a few  scripts helping to convert svgs to inline SVG, which make them accessible for CSS. Tried it and it's working for img-Tags, but none of these solutions are working when using SVG as a div's background-image.

I'm trying to change the color of the SVG, so what I want to do is

```
svg path { fill: #000; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of SVG image using CSS (jQuery SVG image replacement)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement)

Comment: No duplicate. It's providing only solutions for using svgs inside img-Tag - unfortunately.

Comment: You cannot access the DOM of any image. You can reload a different image if you want to change the colour, or you can change the contents of a data URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SCSS – I've made a mixin to handle SVG encoding

Pen:  http://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/doMoML/

SCSS: http://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/GjgXmK.scss

```
$color-1: red;
$color-2: green;

$svg-1: '<svg viewBox="0 0 2 2"><circle fill="#{$color-1}" cx="1" cy="1" r="1"/></svg>';
$svg-2: '<svg viewBox="0 0 2 2"><circle fill="#{$color-2}" cx="1" cy="1" r="1"/></svg>';

.class-1 { @include background-svg($svg-1); } 
.class-2 { @include background-svg($svg-2); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data URI` to import the **SVG** into the CSS.

**HTML**

```
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ... > ... </svg>'>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...> ... </svg>');
}
```

Using this method will allow you to use `fill` to color the **SVG** while using it as a  `background`.

> **Note:** For more information on implementing **SVG** using `data URI` into **CSS**, see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes, this would be a solution, but it would be great if I could keep my svg's in seperate files, so the css file stays clean.

Comment: @Jmie You could create a new CSS file specifically for **SVG** backgrounds. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a solution that would allow you to import **SVG** `data URI` into the CSS document.