# Change svg color on hover?

Tags: css, svg

Here is the code that i have

```
div.dashboard
    svg#menu-btn
        image(xlink:href="/static/icons/svg/menu-1.svg")
```

and the css is

```
#menu-btn:hover {
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    fill: red;
    image {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        fill: red;
    }
}
```

The color of the svg is still black and doesn't turn red. Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Is there a fill applied in the .svg file? You are also not actually declaring that it should change ``red`` on ``:hover``.

Comment: This question is similar did you try this approach ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement

Comment: @Crowes pretty new but looking at the XML i don't see any fill.. Also can't use js on the site. I can change the svg file though

Comment: You need to put the CSS in the SVG or link to it from the SVG file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'll have to inline your SVG to make it work that way.
A second way to do so must be to use css filters or mask, but it is a bit harder.

Comment: if you put the CSS in the SVG it should work. You just can't apply CSS cross-document is all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `fill` for the hover state.

```
svg#menu-button:hover{
     fill:red;
     cursor:pointer; /*to change the cursor*/
    }
```

Comment: my bad... the problem is fill not working... i removed the hover css part just to keep code precise :)

Comment: can you post a codepen / jsfiddle? also check if your svg code already has fill specified like this `fill="#000"?