# Display svg asset with custom fill color

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I have some `svg` files in my project assets.

Using them as the `src` of `img` works fine, but I cannot set their fill color.

`<img src={require('./assets/foo.svg')} alt={props.svg} />`

Using some examples, I tried to use `svg`-`use` combo, but it resulted with a `0x0` `use` element.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <use xlinkHref={require('./assets/foo.svg')} width="80" height="80"/>
</svg>
```

What is the correct way to define an `svg` element from a real `svg` asset? Without of course copying the content of the file.

Comment: how did you try to set the fill colour? I usually just use css to set fill on the entire svg

Comment: indeed the duplicated question is working for me. specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35126817/1236401

Comment: So you're going to use jQuery for something trivial.

Nice.

Comment: you're welcome to propose a trivial solution in that question

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use  ----------------------                       <svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none;">
  <symbol id="blue"viewBox="0 0 30 10"><circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="none"/></symbol>
  </svg>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" >
    <use xlink:href="#blue" style="fill:red" />
    </svg>

Comment: @vssadineni this doesn't use my `foo.svg`

Comment: sorry I was trying to help you to resolve this issue, and not trying to solve it. please replace the path d in the above example with your foo.svg path or other paths and do update the viewbox values as per your foo.svg viewbox and it should work.